# Overloading an operator C++: error: no viable overloaded '='

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, addition

My goal is to **overload the '+' operator** so that I can combine a Paragraph object and a Story object. This function should **return a new Story object** with the paragraph attached to the beginning.

```
Story Paragraph::operator+(const Story& story) {
    Paragraph paragraph;
    Story stry;

    Paragraph storyPara = story.paragraph;
    Sentence paraSentence = storyPara.sentence;

    paragraph.sentence = this->sentence + paraSentence;
    stry.paragraph = paragraph;

    return stry;
}
```

However, when I run all my code *(A Story object should have a paragraph. A Paragraph object should have a sentence. A Sentence object should have a word, etc.)*, I get this error:

**error: no viable overloaded '='**

This occurs when I try to do the following line:

```
paragraph.sentence = this->sentence + paraSentence;
```

I'm not quite sure how to add the sentences together to form a paragraph (to ultimately form & return a new Story). Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Comment: _"you can assume that all my classes are defined properly"_ If that were true, you wouldn't have an error...

Comment: Does the `Sentence` class have a copy constructor or an overloaded `=` operator?

Comment: What problem? We cannot see any pertinent code. Present the [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which you've been debugging the problem over the last few days.

Comment: Show us the definition of `Sentence`.

Comment: Why is operator+ a member of Paragraph class? Makes no sense.

Comment: Also, `Sentence` needs to be posted.

Comment: And `Word` is...?  Also, isn't a Paragraph one or more Sentences?  So why only a Single `Sentence` object in `Paragraph`?

Answer (score 3):

```
you can assume that all my classes are defined properly
```

This is the wrong assumption which causes you this error. 
`Sentence` class has apparently no or wrong `operator=` and/or *copy constructor* defined

Comment: s/copy constructor/copy assignment operator

Comment: bound to be a compiler bug , given that the code is correct :-)

Comment: Oh I forgot to implement a correct operator= . Thanks. Would I just do something along the lines of ... a Story object + Paragraph object equals a new Story object? (And so forth with all other overloaded operater='s).

Comment: @raychul Show us the `Paragraph` class.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Paragraph operator+(const Sentence& sent);
> ```

This declares an operator such that adding two `Sentence`s results in a `Paragraph`.

> ```
> paragraph.sentence = this->sentence + paraSentence;
> ```

The right part of the assignment uses the operator from above, so you are trying to assing a `Paragraph` to a `Sentence`, as if you had written:

```
Paragraph additionResult = this->sentence + paraSentence;
paragraph.sentence = additionResult;
```

The problem is that you have not defined an assignment from `Paragraph` in `Sentence`. You could just add it to `Sentence`, of course:

```
Sentence& operator=(const Paragraph& para);
```

But how would you *implement* it? Can a paragraph logically be converted into a single sentence? This solution will not really work.

An alternative solution is to change the corresponding `operator+` in `Sentence` to return a `Sentence` rather than a paragraph:

```
class Sentence {
    public:
        Sentence();     
        ~Sentence();        
        void show();
        Sentence operator+(const Sentence& sent); // <-- now returns a Sentence
        Paragraph operator+(const Paragraph& paragraph);
        Sentence operator+(const Word& word);

        Word word;              

};
```

When adding two `Sentence`s returns a `Sentence`, then the result of the addition can also be assigned to a `Sentence`, because copy assignment from the same type is automatically generated by the compiler (unless you explicitly `delete` it).

But this presents its own share of problems, because how can two sentences logically be combined into one?

The **real problem** can probably be found in this line:

```
Sentence sentence;      // Sentence in Paragraph
```

Your class definition effectively says that a paragraph always consists of exactly one sentence. This cannot be correct. The member variable should be of type `std::vector<Sentence>` to express the intention that one paragraph consists of *0 to n* sentences. Once you have changed the member variable, rewrite all operator implementations to account for the new situation.

Of course, you have the same problem in `Sentence` (and I guess in your other classes, too).

---

Generally, check your books/tutorials again and review the chapter about operator overloading. You are not following best practices. For example, you should define `+` in terms of `+=`. And of course, an important question is whether operator overloading is actually helpful here or not.